# Permission Denied when editing .bash_profile

Tags: linux, command-line-interface, bash

I'm still learning the CLI and the ins and outs of it, especially this .bash_profile. I feel overwhelmed with what I'm learning about this.

Anyways, I can access .bash_profile. If I do `nano ~/.bash_profile` then the file appears and I'm free to edit. And then I tried addingin the line I'm supposed to include:

`export PATH="/usr/local/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/mysql/bin:$PATH"`

However, when I try to save the file (or whatever .bash_profile is), I get the following error: `[ Error writing /home/myname.bash_profile Permission denied ]`

Answer (score 20):

While you can do `sudo nano ~/.bash_profile` to edit the file, I feel like it's a bit weird that your .bash_profile needs root to be modified.

If you try `ls -la ~ | grep bash`

```
-rw-------    1 Greg  staff    8622 27 Jun 16:06 .bash_history
-rw-r--r--    1 Greg  staff    2189 28 Jun 01:24 .bash_profile
```

You see my .bash_profile is owned by me, Greg, not root. I think you'll find that when you do this, your .bash_profile will be owned by root. This means that when you want to edit the file, you need to use sudo, but I don't.

If you don't want to have to use sudo all the time to modify this file, you can change the owner of the file `sudo chown yourusername ~/.bash_profile`

Now if you run the `ls` command I showed above, you should see your name as the owner of the file, instead of root.

Comment: this is definitely the correct answer. also, an excellent explanation.

Comment: @gykaling But I cant see .bash_profile in ls -la ~ | grep bash ..what Can i do for that?

Answer (score -1):

You need root permissions to edit.

Edit it with sudo or login as root and edit.

Thanks,

Sandeep.